# Zend Framework change view location in plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

I cant find a solution to my problem anywhere, be it on SO or within the actual zend documentation.

Basically i have this setup:

1. I've created a plugin which using Zend_Http_UserAgent and WURFL to detect if the user is currently using a mobile.  This is done in the predispatch.  This works fine
2. I now want to change the view scripts directory if the user is using a mobile.
3. Ideally in a perfect world i'd like to try and load the mobile version of the view, if it exists, if not then load the default view.  But if i can get 2 working at the least then i'll be happy.

I am more than stumped on how i do this.  I've seen i could use:

$view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->view;
$view->setBasePath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/mobile_views/');

But that doesnt seem to do what i expect, plus this happens in postDispatch when i think this sort of thing should happen in preDispatch?

Here is my current plugin:

```
<?php
```

class SQ_Plugins_Mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

```
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $flag) {

    $bootstrap  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam("bootstrap");
    $useragent  = $bootstrap->getResource("useragent");
    $device     = $useragent->getDevice();

    Zend_Registry::set("useragent", $useragent);
    Zend_Registry::set("device", $device);

    echo $device->getType() . " is the type of device";

    if($device->getType() != "mobile") {
        /**
         * Set the layout to be mobile, here we make sure we streamline what is loaded
         * so as to not load things that arent needed.
         */
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout("mobile");


        /**
         * Here i wish to change the view path to be APPLICATION_PATH . "/mobile_views/"
         * @todo Change the view script path 
         */

    }
}

public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

    /**
     * Maybe i have to change the view script path here?
     * @todo change the viewscript path if we're using a mobile
     */

    // Get the current view
    $view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->view;
    $view->setBasePath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/mobile_views/');
    echo "kl;kl;kjhkl;jhlkjhjklhkl;h k;hi";
}
```

}

Comment: You are right, the view change should be set in preDispatch().

Comment: If you are going to save useragent and device in the registry anyway, I'd probably do it back at Bootstrap.

Comment: If the content you deliver is dependent upon user-agent, then you will have the same url delivering different content to different clients depending upon their agent. I'd probably make a subdomain for the mobile version; point the subdomain to the same app space as the web space; do your agent detection in a plugin, redirecting to the mobile subdomain when the user agent qualifies; chain a hostname route that adds a flag to any request for the subdomain; then check that flag in another plugin to set the layout/view/suffix. Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 1):

In your action you could do this if it is a mobile version of the page.

```
$this->view->addBasePath('../application/views/mobile'); // Or whatever your path may be.
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i've fixed it, although i'm not sure it's the best most 'zend' solution, but i think it's quite elegant and works, which is the best one.

So now i check to see if the mobile version of the action view is available, if it is i change the extension to use a mobile suffix.  This allows me to make sure i only load mobile views when i have them, meaning i reduce the potential for errors.

```
class SQ_Plugins_Mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

    $bootstrap  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam("bootstrap");
    $useragent  = $bootstrap->getResource("useragent");
    $device     = $useragent->getDevice();

    Zend_Registry::set("useragent", $useragent);
    Zend_Registry::set("device", $device);

    /**
     * @todo change this to be Mobile 
     */
    if($device->getType() != "mobile") {

        /**
         * Set the layout to be mobile, here we make sure we streamline what is loaded
         * so as to not load things that arent needed.
         */
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout("mobile_layout");

        /**
         * Here we check to see if a mobile version of the template exists.  if it does then we change the view suffix
         * this allows us to load the mobile view if it exists and the defgault view if it doesnt. 
         */
        $base       = APPLICATION_PATH . "/views/scripts/";
        $mobile     = $base .  $request->getControllerName() . "/" . $request->getActionName() . ".mobile.phtml";

        if(is_readable($mobile)) {
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->setViewSuffix('mobile.phtml');      
        } 

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Clearly in myexample above i force the view to be a mobile view everytime.  $device->getType() == "mobile" is what the logic should be